# How do you uninstall Spotify Linux Preview on Ubuntu?

Tags: wine, playonlinux, spotify

I was on PlayOnLinux and saw the Wine version of Spotify and wanted to uninstall the Linux Preview to get the Wine version since it said not enough disk space for the installation so hopefully the uninstallation will help with trying to free space and make some room for the wine installation please give some answers quick! :-)

Answer (score 5):

The following should do the trick. Fire up a terminal by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Then, enter the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove spotify-client
```

If you installed the package manually, then issue the following command instead:

```
sudo dpkg -r spotify-client
```

Comment: That only works if he installed it using apt.

Answer (score 1):

After uninstalling, remember to delete this directory.

> sudo rm -rf /opt/spotify/

Answer (score 1):

Also, if this directory exists it could be quite large:
~/.cache/spotify

```
 sudo rm -rf ~/cache/spotify
```

That's the offline storage for Spotify. It might be there for all users who used the Spotify client.